# Some characters appears as boxes in Windows XP

Tags: character-encoding

I have a website wherein I use the Peso sign "₱" or `&#8369;`

It shows fine on my Windows 7 machine, but doesn't on Windows XP, where it shows up as a box.

How do I "fix" this?

I'm already using: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I also visit other sites that show the Peso sign, and they also show up as a box on my WinXP machine.

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    src: url('../../../other/font/ptsans/pts55f-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../../other/font/ptsans/pts55f-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../../other/font/ptsans/pts55f-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../../other/font/ptsans/pts55f-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../../other/font/ptsans/pts55f-webfont.svg#PTSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#total-payment {
    font: 14px "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="total-payment">Payment Due: &#8369; 1000</p>
```

The glyph appears as a box in:

- Windows XP SP2
- Chrome 34

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows XP machine does not have a font installed that contains this glyph, or at least none that the browser is willing or able to use.

1. If an appropriate font does not exist at all on the machine, you'll have to install one.
2. If a font does exist and the browser is simply not using it, you can alter your CSS and add the appropriate `font-family` to the list of fonts for the site.
3. If 2. doesn't work and 1. is unrealistic for the larger internet public, you can add a web font to your site which contains this character, or embed an image instead of the actual character.

Comment: I'm using an `@font-face` in eot, woff, ttf and svg

Comment: So you're already using a web font that contains that glyph? Then add more information to your question: browser and version, exact code used, exact font used.

Comment: @Obay, if the `@font-face` is relevant to the problem, show the CSS code and related HTML, in the question itself; also specify the source of the font.